# How to know if user came from a Facebook link?

Tags: php, facebook, http, referrer

If there is a link posted on Facebook to my website, and a user follows it, I would like to display custom content using PHP. I tried with the following method...

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Facebook must block this feature because it is not working. Is there a method for this that actually works with Facebook?

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] isn't reliable...the method I know to track where the visitor come from is adding paramters to the url in the link, I dont know if exist another way

Comment: Facebook turns on secure browsing that kinda prevents Referrer, best thing is creating your own link

Comment: How does Google Analytics determine that it was Facebook then?

Comment: Because google already have fb set in there option panel, and they run plenty of campaign on facebook.. They do have some kind of access. I can't say what kind because I dont work with google :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This news is a year old, yet I see they are still using it.. I post it here because It is still pretty informative The srouce of the link is https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10151070897728920

> Restricting the Referrer
>
> We still need to let the websites you navigate to know the traffic is
>   from Facebook, but we also want to prevent them from reading the full
>   source url. Otherwise, they could know where on the site you were when
>   you clicked their link. In order to strike this balance, we've taken
>   advantage of a new feature called the meta referrer, currently
>   available in Chrome 17+ and Safari 6+.  This allows us to specify how
>   much of the source url to share with the external site via the Referer
>   header. If you're using one of these supported browsers you can take
>   advantage of this new feature. Otherwise, your browser will be routed
>   to the slightly slower older system.
>
> This change should reduce the impact of the link shim on your browsing
>   (especially when accessing Facebook from a cellular network) and
>   should help save around a second for a typical user.