# How to know if web page is returned from another website

Tags: php, jquery

I have website link `http://example.com/link/`

How can I handle if it returns from such as: `http://facebook.com`

I want to check and process event by something like this:

```
if(return from facebook) {
}
```

Jquery or PHP is ok.Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Would phps `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` do the job? http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: [How to know if user came from a Facebook link?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19485746/1415724) - You should read that. It's going to answer what you're hoping will work; it won't. Same thing here [How reliable is HTTP_REFERER?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/1415724)

Comment: Thank you, @Fred-ii-. I will read it now.Update: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the referer in PHP using:

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

`if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'https://facebook.com'){
}`

However, you'd probably want to catch anything from facebook;

```
$sReg = '.facebook.+[a-zA-Z](\/*)';

if(preg_match( $sReg, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 1 ){

}
```

Note that `HTTP_REFERER` isn't a sure way of getting the referrer. Often it'll be missing.

See [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for more info

Comment: Thank for your answer but if "HTTP_REFERER isn't a sure way of getting the referrer" then can you use another method for sure?

Comment: unfortunately some browsers wont supply it, be it for privacy or other configuration reasons. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023941/how-reliable-is-http-referer

Comment: No, you can not. Users can decide not to let their browsers to send a referrer, or a fake one. And websites can these days also specify whether they want the browser to send a full referrer, the domain name only, or none at all.

Comment: Thank atoms and Cbroe for your support. I understood.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in javascript

```
if(document.referrer == 'https://facebook.com') {
    /* Do somethings */
}
```

Using Regular Expression:

```
var myRe = new RegExp('facebook.+[a-zA-Z](\/*)');
if(myRe.test(document.referrer)) {
    /* Do somethings */
}
```

Comment: what if someone disables JS? can you answer that detail?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, let me test with this.

Comment: @BuiPhuc Accordingly of your environment, you would use both solutions (PHP and JS) to get a better result.

Comment: @YulioAlemanJimenez: Thank you for your advice. Perhaps I have to combine both js and php.